# Pandas read_sql with pyodbc to handle corrupt data

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, 4d-database

I am working with a client that has a 4D database. Tableau won't connect to it. (That's a whole other problem and if you know the answer to that let me know.) What we've decided to do is essentially keep two copies of the data. I am building a tool in Python that will take any arbitrary table from their database and store a copy of it in a MySQL database. It will then run periodically and update the data as new data is added.

I would prefer to use SqlAlchemy but it does not support 4D. So, I'm using pyodbc with pandas. I'm using

`data_chunks = pandas.read_sql("SELECT * FROM table_name", con=pyodbc_connection, chunksize=100000)`

Then I turn around and use

`chunk_df.to_sql("table_name", con=sqlalchemy_mysql_connection, index=False, if_exists="append")`

to write it to the MySQL database.

Unfortunately on some of the tables I'm reading in, there is corrupt data and I get a `ValueError` saying that `The year xxxxx` is out of range.

The last function called in the trace was `data = cursor.fetchmany(chunksize)` which I believe is from pyodbc.

How can I read data from any arbitrary table and be able to handle the corrupt data gracefully and continue on?

Comment: Sounds like you need to adjust the schema of the MySQL table to allow such "corrupt" data values. Year column may have a constraint of allowable values. Adjust for other columns.

Comment: @Parfait It fails before I ever try to insert it into the MySQL table. I'm pretty sure it's failing when it tries to convert the SQL data types to Python data types.

Comment: So you're getting the error when you execute the `read_sql`?

Comment: Please show fuller code not line snippets including full SQL statement for us to help. We need to see *year* object.

Comment: Also, is the `xxxxx` year value really outside `range(1, 10000)`? If so, that sounds like a bug in the ODBC driver.

Comment: @GordThompson Yes the error occurs when I execute ```read_sql```. Also, the values were really out of range. Around 25600. Unfortunately, there is corrupt data in the 4D database and I can't really do anything about that. I just need to handle it the best I can.

Comment: @Parfait I edited it to show the SQL query. It is simply a SELECT * FROM table query. There is no year object. The error happens when I run that one line with ```read_sql```.

Comment: You might be able to use an [Output Converter function](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Using-an-Output-Converter-function) to work around the issue. If you can identify a specific row with bad data in a specific column then you could start by enabling an [ODBC trace](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Troubleshooting-%E2%80%93-Generating-an-ODBC-trace-log), run a query like`.read_sql("SELECT bad_col FROM table_name WHERE id_col=bad_id", ...` and see the ODBC data type of the offending column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could conceivably use a pyodbc [Output Converter function](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Using-an-Output-Converter-function) to intercept the corrupted date values and "fix" them using code similar to this:

```python
def unpack_sql_type_timestamp(raw_bytes):
    y, m, d, h, n, s, f = struct.unpack("<h5HI", raw_bytes)
    if y > 9999:
        y = 9999
    elif y < 1:
        y = 1
    return datetime.datetime(y, m, d, h, n, s, f)

pyodbc_connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)

pyodbc_connection.add_output_converter(
    pyodbc.SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, 
    unpack_sql_type_timestamp
)

data_chunks = pandas.read_sql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM table_name", 
    con=pyodbc_connection, 
    chunksize=100000
)
```